# Previous quarter max month value in big Query

Tags: date, google-bigquery

I want to see the previous quarter's max month(as a new column) value in the current quarter using a big query.

- When in Q1 2022 it should display `Q4 December 2021` as a new column
- When in Q2 2022 it should display `Q1 March 2022` (in this case 60000)
- When in Q3 2022 it should display `Q2 June 2022` (in this case 40000)

My data is like below

```
date        Sales
2022-09-01  10000
2022-08-02  20000
2022-07-01  30000
2022-06-01  40000
2022-05-01  30000
2022-04-01  50000
2022-03-01  60000
2022-02-01  10000
2022-01-01  89090
```

Output

[image]

Comment: So, you just want one row output, based on today's date?  Or do you want this calculated repeatedly, once for every input row?  ***(Please edit your question, and add the exact results you'd like to see for the example input you've given.)***

Comment: Hi, @MatBailie Thank you so much for the reply. If possible then I looking for something similar to the screenshot I have added in the description

Comment: Why isn't the `2022-09-01` row's previous quarter `50000`?  Why isn't the `2022-06-01` row's previous quarter `89090`?  Why isn't the `2022-03-01` row's previous quarter `NULL`?

Comment: Are the rows *always* on the 1st of each month, and are there *ever* any missing months (such as if sales were 0, would there still be a row, or would there be a gap)?

Comment: 2022-09-01 row's previous quarter is not 50000 because previous quarter ended at June on June 2022-06-01 the value was 40000, same is the case with the rest and yes, in this case, 2022-03-01 value can be null since no data is present .

Comment: if sales were zero then there would be a gap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your given result table fits not the task:  previous quarter's max month.

Here several outputs. Do you want the maximum of the last months, or the values from three month ago? Both columns are included here.

The formula of the 1st month of quarter can be edit to the last month by changing the 1 to -1. As You want zero values for all other months, you need to multiply this with the other column.

Window function do the job. But for each month there must be one row. This is filled up with the `all_months` table.

```sql
with tbl as 
(
Select date("2022-09-01") as dates,  10000 money
union all select date("2022-08-02"),  20000
union all select date("2022-07-01"),  30000
union all select date("2022-06-01"),  40000
union all select date("2022-05-01"),  30000
union all select date("2022-04-01"),  50000
union all select date("2022-03-01"),  60000
union all select date("2022-02-01"),  10000
union all select date("2022-01-01"),  89090

),
all_months as 
(select dates,0 from (Select max(dates) A, min(dates) B from tbl), unnest(generate_date_array(A,B,interval 1 month)) dates)

select *,
if( date_trunc(dates,quarter)= date_trunc(date_sub(dates,interval 1 month),quarter),0,1) as first_month_of_quarter, 
lag(money_max_this_quarter) over (order by dates) as money_max_last_quarter,
lag(money,3) over (order by dates) as money_three_months_ago,
from
(
select * ,
max(money) over (partition by date_trunc(dates,quarter ) ) as money_max_this_quarter
from 
(
  Select dates,sum(money) as money from tbl group by 1
  union all select * from all_months
)
)
order by 1 desc
```